# Access Database Structure Assistance

Tags: sql, database

I'm new to the whole database scene and I need some assistance in coming up with a database structure.

The data I need to store in one table is a ProjectID (primary key), date, #hours logged and employees utilized (1 or more)

The next table would need to have EmployeeID(Primary key), total projects, and total hours.

If I understand normalization correctly, I should not need the second table because those would be calculated when they are needed and not stored. However, I'm not sure how to efficiently store the employees utilized on each project. That is the part that is stumping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you would want a view here. Also your tables are a bit thin at the moment. 
If you want ProejectID as primary key then you could only have one row of information. 
your structure:

```
PID : Date : Hours : Employee (ProjectEmployee table)
4   : today : 3 : 12
4 :  yesterday : 4 : 12 <<<< ERROR cannot insert duplicate Primary key
```

new structure:

```
ID : PID : Date : Hours : Employee (ProjectEmployee table)
1 :  4   : today : 3 : 12
2 :  4   :  yesterday : 4 : 12
```

now in a related table called projects you would have

```
ProjectID : Name (Project Table)
1 : name1
2 : Name2
3 : Name3
4 : Name4
```

Now in order to get what you are actually going for:

Select PID, SUM(Hours) as totalHours, Employee
From ProjectEmployee 
Group by PID,Employee

result:

```
PID : TotalHours : Employee
4   : 7          : 12
```

good luck. 
Mark as answer if that works.

given the following: //updated to show multiple employees working on project four.

```
ID : PID : Date : Hours : Employee (ProjectEmployee table)
1 :  4   : today : 3 : 12
2 :  4   :  yesterday : 4 : 12 
3 : 4    : today    :  3 : 5
```

result from view

```
PID : TotalHours : Employee
4   : 7          : 12
4   : 3          : 5
```

I am not going to bother showing you how you would join the employee table but I assume you can search basic join syntax.

Comment: I wasn't clear on the employee field. For the employees, I need a way to list out which employees were working on the project, not just the number of employees. That is the area I was having an issue with.

Also, you make a good point with everything else. I hadn't thought about the first case.

Comment: I think that is what I need. So I would just have to have a new row for each person that works on the project. So if today I have 3 people work on PID 5, then I would have rows 4-6 with the same information, just a different Employee in the last column.